# Converting a Wordpress page to use Full explicit paths?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm integrating a 3rd party feature into an existing/live Wordpress website using the vendor's Remote HTML Framing Code template.

They are asking me to "convert all paths to full"

Apparently, the Remote HTML Framing Code template needs all URLs on the integration page template to use full explicit paths.

The page template in question is here:
http://www.stonegategardens.com/stonegate-gardens-plant-finder-tool/

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to make this work?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big question. First of all, the stylesheets are currently being added to the header of the document incorrectly. You'll want to [properly enqueue scripts and styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). Doing so will automatically convert paths to absolute.

Second, to get content from your `/wp-content` directory, you'll want to use something like [content_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url) to get the absolute url to the content directory.

Third, you can always return the URL of the site by using [site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url), and the URLs of pages (for example, the links in your navigation) by using [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and doing something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'The Florist' ) ) ); ?>">The Florist</a>
```

Better yet, use WordPress as a CMS, and let it manage the menus by adding proper menus in the admin.

Comment: If that's the case, and if you're adding the menu items properly, it should be returning absolute URLs.